# How should I handle constraining options in a database?

Tags: database-design

For sake of simplicity,

I have a `Gender` table with only 2 values:

```
Male, Female
```

I have another table called `Activity` with a field called `restrict_to_gender`. The values of this field can be any one of the following

```
Male, Female, DoNotLimit
```

I know I can simply create another table called `ActivityGenderLimit` to host these values, but it seems like I am having redundant values, since the Gender table already has the genders.
How do database people handle situations like this?

[Note: i am willing to change my question title, but I didnt know a better one to describe it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraint is the exact keyword you'll want to look into (so it was coincendetaly good verbiage you used).

It depends on the database system you end up using (as they each have their minute and not so minute differences) but in Microsoft SQL Server, for example, they call it a "Check Constraint".

You can read about Check Constraints and how they limit a field to specific values here: [Create Check Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15)

Specifically it sums it up by saying:

> You can create a check constraint in a table to specify the data
> values that are acceptable in one or more columns.

For further supplemental reading, W3Schools has a succinct page on them here: [SQL CHECK Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

They also provide some examples of code implementation across multiple database systems.

Also, if you wanted to use a Table to still hold the values that are enforced by your Check Constraints, in some database systems this is possible. Here's a StackOverflow post with a good example using a Function in the Check Constraint that can reference your values Table: [Can a Check constraint relate to another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table)

Comment: this didnt really answer my question, but it does provides links for me to head to.  I have ibstead asked the question on SO. And got an answer there

Comment: Sorry if I misinterpreted your question. The other way I can understand it would then have me advise that your Gender table have a GenderId field and ActivityGenderLimit table also have a GenderId field that is a reference (creates a relationship) to the Gender table. Then you don't need to store redundant Gender string values.

Comment: Its ok. You have given me enough information. I have modified the question over here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989357/how-should-i-handle-constraining-options-in-a-database  It matches what I really want.  Thanks for the answer and info, I have flagged this answer as correct.